# Import class file from specific jar

Tags: java

I am working with 2 jars , base.jar and derived.jar where I ordered it the class path in this way: base.jar and then derived.jar

I have a problem that I have a class with the same name package in both jars it's third party that I can't change

And in code I want to import the class from the derived.jar with out change the class path order ?

Is there an option to it in my code in the import command or by adding annotation?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own classloader with a predictable jar loading order - yes. But you should instead rename the class/package.

Answer (score 0):

If it is third party and you have the source you can refactor the class yourself and rebuild the jar.